# How can I calculate a Point $P \in E(a, b, \mathbb{F}_p)$ of order $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, elliptic-curves, cryptography, elliptic-functions

> Let $$E(a, b, \mathbb{F}_{p} ) = y^2 = f(x) = x^3 + ax + b$$
>   Find for $E(-4, 0, \mathbb{F}_{541} )$ all points of order $2$ and one point of order $3$.

In this case the points of order $2$ are easy to calculate, because these are the roots of polynom $f(x)$ (where $y = 0$). 
$$x^3 - 4x = (x - 2)(x + 2)$$
Thus $2P :=\{ (0,\,0), (2,\,0), (-2,\,0)\}$
Now, how can I calculate a Point $P : 3P = \mathcal{O}$?
I only deduce that:
$$3P =  P + P + P \implies P + P = -P \implies 2P = -P$$
How can I continue here to find $P$?

Comment: The given polynomial has degree four in $\;x\;$ , but all your symbols and even tagging say "Elliptic Curves" ...how come?

Comment: $$x^3 - 4x = (x - 2)(x + 2)$$  ...how come?

Comment: @Darío   Ah, now we're talking. :)

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, it was a typing error :)

Comment: @DonAntonio $x^3 - 4x = x(x^2 - 4) \implies x((x-2)(x+2))$ because $\pm 2$ is root of $x^2 - 4$ then it is also from $x((x-2)(x+2)) = x^3 - 4x$. it is right?

Comment: Hmmm....I still am confused. According to your notation, $\;a=-4\,,\,b=0\;$ , so the equation should be $\;y^2=x^3-4x^2\;$ (which by the way has singular points...). Perhaps you meant $\;y^2=x^3+a\color{red}x+b\;$ ,and thus $\;a=-4,\,b=0\implies y^2=x^3-4x\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry! I correct the error

Comment: Any ideas??????

Comment: @DonAntonio You were right to guess that there was a typo, but the curve $y^2 = x^4 + ax^2 + b$ is an elliptic curve, provided that the discriminant $16 b (-a^2 + 4 b)^2$ is nonzero (so the curve is nonsingular).  It’s just not in Weierstrass form.

Comment: @Quasicoherent I don't think the usual definition makes room for that, though I agree that the algebraic geometry definition (irreducible curve of genus one) could apply. Anyway, and by the use of the coefficients, it was *almost sure* a cubic was due instead of a quartic or whatever in this case.

Answer (score 1):

By eye: input in values for $\;x\;$  and find out, for example with the help of  Legendre's symbol and quadratic reciprocity, whether you have a solution. To *actually* find the solution may be way messier, but at least you'll already know whether there exists one or not. For example (note that $\;541=1\pmod4\;$):

$$x=3\implies 3^3-4\cdot3=15\;,\;\;\left(\frac{15}{541}\right)=\left(\frac3{541}\right)\left(\frac5{541}\right)=\left(\frac{541}3\right)\left(\frac{541}5\right)=$$

$$=\left(\frac13\right)\left(\frac15\right)=1\cdot1=1\implies \text{there exists}\;\;\sqrt{15}\pmod{541}$$

After some work (you can use the web for this), one finds $\;\sqrt{15}=\pm189\pmod{541}\;$  ,so we have the solutions  $\;(3,189),\,(3,-189)=(3,352)\;$

You can do the above for several values of $\;x\pmod{541}\;$ , but it is going to take a while...and then you have to check what their order in the group is carrying on the operation... You can use the web to make calculations easier, or you can even build a computer program to do the calculations, but it is going to be weary. Why do you think there's a point of order three, btw?

Answer (score 1):

In general one can use [division polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials) to compute the coordinates of the $n$-torsion points of an elliptic curve.  In this example, the third division polynomial is
$$
\psi_3 = 3x^4 + 517x^2 + 525 = 3(x^2 + 148)(x^2 + 385)
$$
and its roots give the $x$-coordinates of the $3$-torsion points.  Since $x^2 + 148$ and $x^2 + 385$ have no roots in $F = \mathbb{F}_{541}$, then there are no nontrivial $3$-torsion points defined over $F$.  Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^2 + 148$ and let $K = F(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{F}_{541^2}$.  Then $\psi_3$ factors over $K$ as
$$
\psi_3 = 3(x - \alpha)(x + \alpha)(x - 178 \alpha)(x + 178 \alpha)
$$
so the $x$-coordinates of the $3$-torsion points are $\pm \alpha, \pm 178 \alpha$.  Unfortunately the $y$-coordinates of these points are not defined over $K$, so letting $\beta = \sqrt{\alpha^3 - 4\alpha}$ and $L = K(\beta) \cong \mathbb{F}_{541^4},$
we find that the nontrivial $3$-torsion points of $E$ are
$$
(\alpha, \pm \beta), \ (-\alpha, \pm 52 \beta), \ (178 \alpha, \pm 86 \beta), \ (-178\alpha, \pm 144\beta) \, .
$$

Another more elementary approach would be to use your equation $2P = -P$.  Writing $P = (x,y)$, then $-P = (x,-y)$.  The coordinates of $2P$ can also be expressed in terms of $x$ and $y$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_addition)), and equating these with the coordinates of $-P$ will give you a system of equations to solve.  (I think the equation you get for the $x$-coordinate will be $\psi_3 = 0$, so the two approaches should be equivalent.)